# How to substitute this pickle switch with a software controlled switch?

Tags: switches, bnc

I'm working as a research assistant. We have three high frame rate cameras that currently save the recorded video when the pickle switch (purple cord) is manually pressed. I want to replace this purple pickle switch cable with a microcontroller that can automatically send a trigger signal to the cameras when receiving a signal from a Linux machine. I tried searching google for "software pickle switch" and there were too many extraneous results. How should I go about doing this?[image: purple pickle]

I'm also confused about the actual circuit that is created between these 3 BNC connectors and the pickle switch. I'm told by another research assistant that the pickle switch grounds the BNC cables. Is that correct? What would the actual circuit look like if drawn on a schematic?

Edit: Here is what I think the circuit is actually like. I measured the resistance of the BNC pickle connector and it short circuits when the button is pressed.
[image]

Comment: I'll bite (pun intended)...what the heck is a pickle switch? Can you provide a link to a manufacturer's datasheet for such a thing? Where do all of the BNC cables go in the photograph? Are there any markings on the BNC connectors?

Comment: My first guess would be that the "pickle switch" is a simple normally-open pushbutton that shorts the BNC center conductor and shield when pressed.  This can be easily tested with an ohmmeter.  If that is so, it could be replaced with a relay contact.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson The three black BNC cables are "inputs" while the purple pickle cable is the "switch".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've never heard of a "pickle switch" but they seem to be a simple pushbutton on a cable.

[image]

*Figure 1. A pickle switch from [AbelCine](https://www.abelcine.com/buy/cameras-accessories/cables-3/vri-trigger-pickle-switch-cable-6).*

To prove my theory:

- Disconnect the "pickle switch".
- Test for continuity with a multimeter on Ω range.
- Record resistance with button released.
- Record resistance with button pressed.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2feEsOh.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 2. Likely result.*

If it works out to be as shown in Figure 2 then you can replace it with a relay contact. The coil of your relay will be driven by the Linux machine. The simplest solution may be a USB relay module but you'll need to check for suitable Linux drivers.

Comment: Sorry, I assumed pickle switch was a common term. This is pretty much the same thing we have here in the lab.

Comment: @snowg It may well be a common term in the area you work in! It just isn't, apparently, outside it.